# What is a difference between "make an effect" and "have an effect"

Tags: word-difference

According to a dictionary both "make an effect" and "have an effect" are right expressions.

Is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally different. The word "effect" has multiple meanings (and so has "affect"), which causes native speakers to trip over alot. Sorry, not alot, but a lot. Alot is a small town somewhere in India. Never use the word alot unless you are talking about that town.

Anyway: "Effect" is the result of doing something. Dropping the bucket had the effect of covering the floor with water. "Effect" is also used in the film industry for creating images that are not real. The people who create images in the film industry make effects.

Using this toothpaste has a noticeable effect on the whiteness of your teeth.

James and his team made the effect of the exploding Death Star.

Answer (score 0):

They have mostly the same meaning, their usage depends on the context.
 "Has an effect" sounds a little more formal and can be used in sentences like "Smoke has an effect on health". 
In that case "Make an effect" wouldn't sound great and I would keep it for small talk.